# Polymer - Force observer event

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm creating a breadcrumb element for managing product category depth. I have a property `categoryOut` which a category loader element is bound to. When this property changes from a click somewhere in the breadcrumb chain, the corresponding category is loaded.

For instance, a breadcrumb list could look like this:

`Cars -> Ford -> Focus`

If you click on Cars, the breadcrumb `categoryOut` property changes, and the Cars category is loaded. My problem is: If you don't click on any other breadcrumb link, and click on Cars again after loading more categories, the property isn't changed, and the observer event is never triggered.

To make it work, I'm setting the `categoryOut` property to empty, and then to the actual value when a breadcrumb is clicked. This feels like a hack to me though. I'm wondering if there's a way I can force the observer to fire without the value changing.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case loading the category data could be better done inside the click/tap event of the breadcrumb elements. If you are using a dom-repeat template use the **itemForElement** method of the template to get the bound data item for the clicked item. ([Example here](http://hugozap.com/development/2015/10/18/polymer-itemforelement-example/))

Using the observer in this case may not be ideal, because for Polymer the actual value of the selected category does not change if the user clicks the element twice.